# Use mootools Fx to zoom background-size

Tags: javascript, css, mootools

I'm trying to use mooTools Fx to zoom the background image of a div. I followed [david welshs article](http://davidwalsh.name/css-transforms) To make custom transformations. My mooTools/js skills are just quite basic, so

Also I am wondering if there is a possibility to incorporate to use a sine transitions for example (though it doesn't look like).

Here's what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/q2GQ7/

Javascript:

```
$$('#program a').each(function(item, index){
    item.store('BackgroundZoomer', new Fx({ duration: 250}));
});
$$('#program a').each(function(item, index){
    item.retrieve('BackgroundZoomer').set = function(value) {
    var style = 200+value + "px " +200+value + "px";
    this.setStyle('background-size', style);
    };
});
$$('#program a').each(function(item, index){
    addEvents({
      'mouseenter': function(){   
            item.retrieve('BackgroundZoomer').start(0, 200); },
        'mouseleave': function(){
            item.retrieve('BackgroundZoomer').cancel();}
    });
});
```

Comment: Youre fiddle throws errors to the console.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige Thanks, I just updated it. Not it's not syntax anymore, but logic. Not sure how to apply the effect to the element.

Comment: I still get an Unexpected token )  error :)

Comment: wait what? Backgroundzoomer is an INSTANCE of Fx class but you then try to make an instance of the instance which is not a constructor? something is wrong. i blame david, but it's what you get of arsenal fans

Comment: You're right... that was weird. I changed it, but this seems not to be intended to work like this. Do I have to make a new Fx object for each element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this looked like fun, I wrote some code in the MooTools way[tm] to get you started. I don't normally do this as it's contrary to SO style but I miss working with MooTools. so meh...

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/dNd3H/

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    var Fx = this.Fx;

    // keep the set override private
    Fx.Background = new Class({
        Extends: Fx,
        initialize: function(element, options){
            this.element = element;
            this.parent(options);
        },
        set: function(value, u){
            u = this.options.unit;
            this.element.setStyle('background-size', [value, u, ' ', value, u].join(''));
            return this;
        }
    });

    document.getElements('#program a').each(function(item) {
        item.store('fxb', new Fx.Background(item, {
            duration: 250,
            link: 'cancel',
            unit: '%' // change to px or em 
        }));
    });

    document.id('program').addEvents({
        'mouseover:relay(a)': function(){
            // 100% to 200%
            this.retrieve('fxb').start(100,200);
        },
        'mouseout:relay(a)': function(){
            // 200% back to 100%
            this.retrieve('fxb').start(200,100);
        }
    });
}.call(this));
```

### Explanation:

- Closure. good practice.
- Creating a subclass that extends Fx but expects a new argument, the element--similar to how Fx.Morph and Fx.Tween work. Benefits are: available via Fx object anywhere. Can access normal `options` object, therefore it will be possible to use `unit` etc in the set. scope will be correctly bound to `Fx` instance, NOT the element like in David's demo.
- Instantiate a new class for the elements

> Look at Fx.Tween.js source. Normally your classes extend Fx.Tween, this fix is kind of an anti-pattern / hack, Fx instantiation direct is not common at all :) You really should just extend the `Fx.CSS.Parser` and `Element.Styles` properties instead to be able to read / parse what you need and Fx will just work like with any other property.

- add a single event to parent via delegation.

Comment: Splendid, you're awesome, thank you! Is there a specific reason why you avoid the dollar/s function (maybe because you save it for JQuery)? Curious for you're follow-up (not sure if you can edit an accepted answer so I'll do that later)!

Comment: ok then. Thanks for your explanation. I didn't understand his approach, but in general he's pretty useful :). I'll probably give it a try to make it more "common".

Comment: `document.id` because `$` is unsafe and it is only an alias for `document.id` anyway. and `node.getElements` is more specific, I like code to say what it does so `menuElement.getElements('a')` is good. plus in FireBug or inspector, $$ is defined to QSA.